# JavaScript objects and literal notation

Tags: javascript, object

I just cleared my mind on JavaScript objects and my question is really simple for most of the people here. I feel comfortable with the JavaScript object literal notation like:

```
var Obj = {
    /**
     * @type {string}
     */
    name: '',

    /**
     * setName
     * Set the `name` property.
     * 
     * @param param
     */
    set setName (param) {
        this.name = param;
    }
};
```

The only limit I found is that if I want to create two completely separate objects in the same page, with this notation I can't.

```
var a = Obj;
a.setName = "John";

var b = Obj;
b.setName = "Peter";

// OUTPUT
// a.name -> Peter
// b.name -> Peter
```

Set `var whatever = Obj` is just useless, 'cause it doesn't instantiate `n` separate objects and it just overwrites the code above. Using `new` keyword such as `var a = new Obj` doesn't work neither (probably I'm using it in the wrong way?). The solution I came up with is returning the object inside a function, like:

```
function Obj() {
    return {
        /**
         * @type {string}
         */
        name: '',

        /**
         * setName
         * Set the `name` property.
         *
         * @param param
         */
        set setName (param) {
            this.name = param;
        }
    }
}
```

This way I can create two different objects and correctly access to their properties and methods:

```
var a = Obj();
a.setName = "John";

var b = Obj();
b.setName = "Peter";

// OUTPUT
// a.name -> John
// b.name -> Peter
```

So, my question are:

- Is what I've done conceptually right?
- Is there a more correct/efficient way to achieve it?

Comment: You can do `var a = {...Obj, name: "Peter"} `

Comment: This is a *primarily opinion-based* question because you're going to get a lot of **opinions** based of experiences, Etc.  Therefore, this question should be closed.

Comment: @IngoBürk I didn't get it :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: @Ele I don't think I could get more opinions than the JavaScript language admits; and know the possibilities JavaScript gives me is actually the aim of this question

Comment: I hope, but certainly, this question could generate answers regarding to experiences and not objective concepts.  For example, *Is there a more correct/efficient way to achieve it?* that question is not objective because the members from SO will answer what they think about it rather than an objective answer with resources, Etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concept of a function that returns an `Object` instance is valid, but your implementation is very brittle because it is only set up to work with specific properties. Read on for more details on various ways to create instances and a more flexible way to return objects...

`var a = Obj;` doesn't create a new object. It just assigns `a` the memory address of the existing object `Obj`.

```js
var myObj = {}; // Object instance is created and memory location is stored in myObj 
var a = myObj;  // No new object is created. a and myObj point to the same object
console.log("Are 'a' and 'myObj' both pointing to the same object?", a === myObj);  // true
```

If you want to design a single object and then make more of that object, you need to be able to create "instances" of an object. You can't do that *directly* with an object literal:

```js
var myObj = {
  someProp:10
};

var myNewObj = new myObj(); // Fails because an object literal can't be instantiated
```

But, you can do it with the **[`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)** method, **which takes your `Obj` concept to fruition**:

```js
// Object instance is created and memory location is stored in myObj 
var myObj = {
  someProp: "default",
  
  // "Methods" are just properties with functions as their value
  someMethod: function(input){
    // The || syntax that follows allows for a default value for the method
    // if no argument is passed to the method.
    this.name = input || "default";
  }
}; 

// Create a new Object instance and set myObj as the prototype of the instance.
// This means that the new instance will inherit from that prototype:
var a = Object.create(myObj);  

console.log(a.someProp);  // "default";
a.someProp = "something specific";
a.someMethod("Test");
myObj.someMethod();
console.log(a.name, myObj.name);             // "Test" "default"
console.log(a.someProp, myObj.someProp);     // "something specific", "default"
```

Instances can be explicitly made with the **[`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)** and a constructor function:

```js
function foo(){
 this.someProp = "something";
}

var a = new foo(); // Unique instance of foo
var b = new foo(); // Separate and distinct instance of foo

a.someProp = 10;
b.someProp = 20;
console.log(a.someProp, b.someProp);  // 10 20
```

Or, the `new` operator and a **[class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)**:

```js
class foo{
  constructor(val) {
    this.someProp = val;
  }
}

var a = new foo(10); // Unique instance of foo
var b = new foo(20); // Separate and distinct instance of foo   

console.log(a.someProp, b.someProp);  // 10 20
```

Comment: I didn't consider classes in my question because I'm looking for a 'no-classes' way, while the `Object.create()` solution is just great! I also tried the solution with the constructor function, but when I try to add methods (e.g. a setter method for name) it doesn't work; could you expand that solution with a method? Thanks Scott, you're answer definitely clarified all my doubts!

Comment: @Brigo I will update the answer to show how a method is created, but quickly... There really is no such thing as a "method" or a "setter" in JavaScript. You just create a property that contains a function for its value.

Comment: Yes, my problem with the 'constructor-function solution' I guess is the syntax, because I tried something like `function foo() { this.someProp = "something"; this.setName = function (param) { foo.name = param; } }` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Brigo  Change `foo.name = param;` to `this.name = param;` because `foo` is the name of the constructor function, not the instance(s) generated from it. `this` inside of an Object being used to construct other objects represents the future instances made from the constructor.

Comment: No more doubts now, your answers are just great and explanatory! Thanks Scott

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) ?

```js
var b = { setName : "Mongo" };
a = Object.create(b);
a.setName = "John";
b.setName = "Peter";

console.log(a.setName);
console.log(b.setName);
```